# How to store sales in groups of orders

Tags: mysql, transactions, shopping-cart

For a purchase-scenario:

I have a table (PRODUCTS) that contain columns like NAME, TYPE, DEFAULTPRICE, ID and a table with sales (SALES) that contain columns like DATE, ID, PRICE, AMOUNT where ID in SALES is a foreign key to primary key ID in PRODUCTS. Very simple, not much to mess up there.

This works fine as long as you insert one row of whichever product (and how many) at what total price.

BUT - let's say I want to design this system to support "basket"-kind of shopping. I.e. a user selects several items that are not the same product ID, but gets a single ORDER ID that contains all the products that were included in the order, the amount of each product, the total price, date etc.

How would one go about creating this? I was thinking maybe creating a table called "ORDERS" and link every row from SALES to an ID from ORDERS - but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would create a table called `Orders` for each order.  It would have whatever information you want about the order.

You would then have a table for the products in each order.  A common name is `OrderLines`.  This would have an `OrderId`, linking it to the `Orders` table and a `ProductId` linking to the `Products` table.

Comment: So basically renaming my "Sales" table to OrderLines yields the same result as what I was thinking in my last two lines, yes?

Comment: @nickdnk . . . I wouldn't call the tables `Orders` and `Sales`.  That isn't clear, but it is your database so you can use your naming conventions.

Comment: Yeah. I realize the names are unfortunate. It was to clarify if we actually meant the same thing to begin with, table names aside.